Want to generate a token for accessing the application with associated users information from a particular tenant
I am new to Azure Portal,I have premium p2 subscription, I want to generate a token using Client Credentials flow type, Basically want to read my application and users associated with my Tenant. I am using Postman for calling API.
I tried but not able to achieve desired output.I am confused with which API should I call.

Created an Microsoft Entra ID Application like below:

Note: If you want to read all users and applications of tenant , Add permissionUser.Read.All and Application.Read.All.
Adding Application.Read.All and User.Read.All like below:

Now you need to generate Access Token by Postman
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id: <application id>
client_secret: <client secret>
grant_type: client_credentials
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default


Generated Access Token:

After Successfully generating access token, Now use the Access token to list Users and Application in Tenant.
1. List the User
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

2.List the Applications
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications

References:
List the Users
List the Applications
